# Munin disable dynazoom.html

Tags: munin, system-monitoring, graph

Doing a quick google search for "Munin dynazoom.html doesn't work" yields many results. There doesn't seem to be a solution that works -- at least not that I have seen. I have munin installed on a small nginx VPS.

I'd like to edit the template files so that if we click on a graph it doesn't direct to the broken dnyazoom.html page -- like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObrDt.png

Could someone please show how to do that? Perhaps instead of linking to the broken dynazoom.html page we can link to a much larger graphic?

Comment: I have dynazoom working on apache.  It doesn't specifically answer your question, but rather than working to disable it altogether you might try getting it working under a different software stack.